# $P\{X_t=-X_t \}=1$

Tags: probability, brownian-motion

If we define that $X_t$ is Brownian motion over space $(\Omega,\mathcal F ,\mathcal F_t;P) $,

then why is it true that the fact that $X_t$ is Brownian motion implies that $P\{X_t=-X_t \}=1$ is impossible?

I would be grateful if anyone could help me.

best , Educ

Comment: If $P(X_t=-X_t)=1$ then $P(X_t=0)=1$ since $\{X_t=-X_t\}=\{X_t=0\}$ but $P(X_t=0)=0$ since $X_t$ is normally distributed (that is absolutely continuous).

Comment: Honestly I find stunning that a same user can ask the present question and [this previous one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/384878/). Somehow, something does not add up.

Comment: Thanks Mr Henrik  ,with respect to Mr Did please you should  to understand even i have master's degree in math but i had no contact with math for 4 years that's why i ask like that question to refresh my memory  best Educ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered by Henrik in the comments: $P(X_t=-X_t)=P(X_t)=0$ because $X_t$ has a continuous distribution (namely, normal).

That said, the Brownian motion started at $0$ has the following symmetry property: for every measurable set $A\subset \mathbb R$ and every $t\ge  0$,
$$P(X_t\in A) = P(-X_t\in A)$$
Which is a consequence of $X_t$  and $-X_t$  having the same distribution.